# completion of a complete metric space is itself

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$  is  a  complete  metric  space  and $(Y,d)$  is  its  completion . What  can  be  said  from  this $?$.

I  think  $Y=X$  is  the  answer .  Am  I  correct  $?$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Indeed. $X$ would be dense in $Y$ (every point in $Y$ is either in $X$ or a limit point of $X$). But then, as $X$ is complete, it contains those limit points.

Comment: Maybe isomorphic? If the completion is taken to be equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, etc, then you don't have equality per se.